# Getting error,Error: org.kitesdk.data.DatasetIOException: Cannot decode Avro value

Tags: hadoop, sqoop, amazon-redshift, parquet

I am trying to load data from redshift on to `hdfs(parquet format)`,using `sqoop(--as-parquetfile)`.

Has anyone else encountered this same error (see below)? If so, how did you go about fixing the problem?

```
Error: org.kitesdk.data.DatasetIOException: Cannot decode Avro value
        at org.kitesdk.data.spi.SchemaUtil.fromString(SchemaUtil.java:419)
        at org.kitesdk.data.spi.predicates.In.fromString(In.java:47)
        at org.kitesdk.data.spi.predicates.Predicates.fromString(Predicates.java:85)
        at org.kitesdk.data.spi.Constraints.fromQueryMap(Constraints.java:468)
        at org.kitesdk.data.mapreduce.DatasetKeyOutputFormat.loadOrCreateTaskAttemptView(DatasetKeyOutputFormat.java:577)
        at org.kitesdk.data.mapreduce.DatasetKeyOutputFormat.getRecordWriter(DatasetKeyOutputFormat.java:426)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewDirectOutputCollector.<init>(MapTask.java:644)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:764)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:341)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:163)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1628)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:158)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException
        at org.apache.avro.io.BinaryDecoder.readInt(BinaryDecoder.java:153)
        at org.apache.avro.io.BinaryDecoder.readIndex(BinaryDecoder.java:423)
        at org.apache.avro.io.ResolvingDecoder.doAction(ResolvingDecoder.java:229)
        at org.apache.avro.io.parsing.Parser.advance(Parser.java:88)
        at org.apache.avro.io.ResolvingDecoder.readIndex(ResolvingDecoder.java:206)
        at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.read(GenericDatumReader.java:152)
        at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.read(GenericDatumReader.java:139)
        at org.kitesdk.data.spi.SchemaUtil.fromString(SchemaUtil.java:417)
        ... 13 more
```

Thanks for any suggestions you may have.

Comment: please provide the code for how/what caused this for us to derive a solution

Comment: the error occurs only with tables that has a float8/double precision datatype in redshift.

Comment: sqoop import --driver "com.amazon.redshift.jdbc41.Driver" --connect "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:port/database" --username "username" --password "password" --table "schema"."table" --target-dir /user/huser/pq_mobile_og_pages_2 --as-parquetfile -m 1
This is the command that i have used and works fine with tables that doesnt have float8/double precision, but only throws error when the table contains a float8/double precision column.